# Replacing dos executable names with custom short names?

Tags: path, cmd, command-prompt

I've been using the command prompt to practice assembly programs and I wish to use notepad++ as the editor. Adding notepad++ to the path will do the job but I don't want to type 'notepad++' each time  I have to edit a file. Is there a way I can change the name of the executable? Without having to rename the application name.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a quick batch file called, say, `npp.cmd`.  That batch file only needs to have this in it:

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

Put `npp.cmd` somewhere in your path (I have a `C:\tools` directory for batch files like this) and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

Or associate your assembler sources with Notepad++.

```
 ASSOC .asm=asmfile
 FTYPE asmfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

Then you can edit *.asm files with Notepad++ by double clicking on it in Explorer or by writing it's name in command prompt.